# Android search widget crashes after changing toolbar text to all caps in style

Tags: android, android-layout, indexoutofboundsexception

My app has a search widget present in its toolbar.
It works fine normally but if i change the text to all caps in the style by adding:

```xml
 <style name="toolbar_text parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
 <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
 <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
 </style>
```

The app crashes when I try to use the search widget text field but one point to be noted here is the voice search works fine so how to fix this

here these are the errors

```
E/ACRA: ACRA caught a IndexOutOfBoundsException for com.lalitesh.datenoteapp
                                     java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
                                         at android.graphics.Paint.getRunAdvance(Paint.java:2557)
                                         at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:719)
                                         at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:869)
                                         at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:387)
                                         at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:277)
                                         at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:943)
                                         at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:921)
                                         at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:892)
                                         at android.widget.TextView.bringPointIntoView(TextView.java:7544)
                                         at android.widget.TextView.updateAfterEdit(TextView.java:8261)
                                         at android.widget.Editor.finishBatchEdit(Editor.java:1460)
                                         at android.widget.Editor.endBatchEdit(Editor.java:1442)
                                         at android.widget.TextView.endBatchEdit(TextView.java:6675)
                                         at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.endBatchEdit(EditableInputConnection.java:78)
                                         at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:478)
                                         at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:91)
                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to all caps.

You are missing a closing double quote at the `name="toolbar_text"` property in the XML.

Try this:

```xml
<style name="toolbar_text" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
   <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
   <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: do you have a stack trace of the crash? can you post it on your question please?